# Rigid body constraint not working

Tags: physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I want some physics with movement in the z and without rotation in the x and y.
(SO basicly 2d physics).

I added a rigid body constraint but for some reason it is not working and I can't figure out why. What is it I do wrong?

[image: my setup]